# Narrow SonarQube analysis to single commit

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube analysis in our project lasts arround 5 hours, because of large code base.
Is there any way to narrow SonarQube analysis to single commit, so that after push, sonarqube will analyse only that single commit, and form report, based on new code in this commit?

I expect a solution, that allow sonarqube to run analysis on single commit or any other solution, so analysis time will be shortened as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

Which scanner do you use or which language do you want to analyze?
As far as I understood the [release notes 9.9 LTS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/release-upgrade-notes/#release-9.9-upgrade-notes) there is now an incremental analysis with the .NET scanners available. This is propably the nearest thing you'll find.

By the way, I assume you want to analyze a push to the CI pipeline, not a single commit.

Comment: SQ Community EditionVersion 8.8 (build 42792) with Jenkins, Java.
> I assume you want to analyze a push to the CI pipeline
Yes, I think that's correct